# C++, user input check for '\0' stops at spaces?

Tags: c++, console-application

If the user inputs a sentence containing spaces the while loop stops at one of these spaces. Why is this happening? are '\0' and a space the same or did i do something else wrong?

```
int main ( )
{
    char user_input[200];
    cin>>user_input;
    int i=0;
    while(user_input[i]!='\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    cout<<i;
    return 1;

}
```

Thanks everyone, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Use `std::string`, not `char[]`. You have a buffer overflow vulnerability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\0` is the null terminating character with ASCII code `0`.
Space is another character with ASCII 32 i suppose.
In fact you are doing this.

```
cin >> user_input;
```

It takes input till you press space or enter. So no space is present in your `user_input` string.
Use this instead of `cin`.

```
cin.getline (user_input, 200, '\0') ;
```

Comment: How does the user enter a null character from the keyboard?  Is that even possible?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley you can pipe to `stdin`. The keyboard is irrelevant.

Comment: @daknøk: Okay.  Is that what's really wanted here though?  I'm pretty sure the OP's intention is to just read until a newline. (from a user who is using a keyboard)

Comment: The answer isn't really correct, since `cin >> user_input;` stops at any white space, not just a space character, and it skips any leading white space as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with reading using `>>` into a char array. It splits at whitespace when tokenizing. Try printing `user_input` to screen to confirm this.

Using `getline` into a `std::string` is generally safer in this context (as mentioned by daknøk). And I assume the input is likely to be terminated by a carriage return?

```
std::string user_input;
std::getline( std::cin, user_input, '\n' );
```

Comment: When inputting to a string, you have to use the free function form of `getline`: `std::getline( std::cin, user_input );`.  (The default is `'\n'`, so you don't have to specify it.  And it is `'\n'`, and not `"\n"`, which shouldn't compile.)

Comment: @JamesKanze You are correct in every point. I was being somewhat careless. My apologies. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your input stops reading when white space is entered. You can use

`cin.unsetf(ios::skipws)`

By default it is set to skip white spaces. With this you will get your desired result.