# How to compare input with ASCII code?

Tags: c++, while-loop, compare, ascii

I am trying to write a console program, which gets a number from the input and puts it into an array. The read in lasts as long as the user does not hit the "space" button. I have tried several things, but my program won't compare the input with the ASCII code of "space". Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int fabcd[25],number_of_items = 0;
    cout << "The read in loop lasts while you don't hit space:\n";
    while((char)cin.get() != 32)
    {
            cin >> fabcd[number_of_items];
            number_of_items++;      
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it will then get an integer input, and will compare to the number 32

Comment: maybe cin.get() won't work this way or something

Comment: nah it treats it like a char, but still won't work xD

Comment: The stream defaults to whitespace-skipping behaviour.  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774825/reading-from-ifstream-wont-read-whitespace

Comment: wait! what's this? `cin >> fabcd[number_of_items]`

Comment: you should `char a=cin.get();` then `fabcd[number_of_items]=a`

Comment: @Immueggpain Maybe.  It depends on what he wants to do.  If he wants to read an integer (one or more characters forming a number), he needs `>>` somewhere.  If he wants to read digits, then `int a = std::cin.get();` is the correct solution.  It is _never_ correct to assign the results of `std::cin::get()` to a `char` before having tested for end of file.

Comment: @TonyD White space is only skipped on formatted input (`>>`).  Never for `std::cin::get()`.

Comment: @JamesKanze, True. See my answer below. It's something else wrong.

Comment: @Immueggpain There's more than one thing wrong, and it's not even clear what the OP is trying to do.  See my answer, below.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your code.  The most fundamental
is that you do two inputs each time through the loop, the first
in the `while`, and the second using `>>` in the loop.  Note too
that the second will skip any spaces, then convert the input to
an integer.  If the input cannot be legally converted to an
integer (e.g. the next character is an `'a'`), the input goes
into an error state, and `cin.get()` will always return `EOF`.
And of course, if you are entering numbers, you can easily
enter more than `25`, and overrun the buffer.

If you just want to enter a sequence of numbers, then:

```
std::vector<int> fabcd;
int tmp;
while ( std::cin >> tmp ) {
    fabcd.push_back( tmp );
}
```

is all you need.  (The numbers must be separated by white
space.)  If you want to enter the *digits*, up until you
encounter a white space, something like the following should
work:

```
std::vector<int> digits;
int tmp = std::cin.get();
while ( tmp != EOF && ! std::isspace( tmp ) ) {
    digits.push_back( tmp /* or tmp - '0' */ );
    tmp = std::cin.get();
}
```

Notice that the results of `std::cin.get()` are assigned to an
`int`, *not* a `char`.  This function returns an `int`
intentionally, because it must be able to return the out of band
value `EOF`.  There are a couple of variants on this: if you use
`std::cin::peek()`, instead of `std::cin::get()`, you'll not
actually extract the character (which you'll have to do in the
loop); and there is also `std::get( char& )`, which extract the
character into the given `char`, provided it isn't at EOF.
Using this function, the loop would be:

```
std::vector<int> digits;
char tmp;
while ( std::get( tmp ) && ! std::isspace( tmp ) ) {
    digits.push_back( tmp );
}
```

(You might also want to use `std::isdigit`, instead of `!
std::ispace` to control the loop.)

### EDIT:

One last point: the actual numeric code for a space or whatever
depends on the implementation, and is *not* necessarily 32.
Also, you'll want to handle tabs and newlines similarly.  You
should always use the `isspace`, etc. functions.  Or if you
really do want to check for a space, and only a space, compare
with `' '`, and not 32.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth answer. I will study it through :)

Answer (score 0):

(char)13 ist the carriage return not the space.

isn't the point that you would do:

```
((char)cin.Get()) !=' '
```

Answer (score 0):

The acii code for space is 32. So you should substitute 64 or 13, which is carraiage return to 32:

```
while((char)cin.get() != 32)
```

However the problem might be that cin may stop on some characters for example whitespace: You can disable this behaviour by setting: cin.unsetf(ios::skipws);
according to [C++, user input check for '\0' stops at spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014272/c-user-input-check-for-0-stops-at-spaces)

Comment: The thing is I have tried with 32, then wanted to try with the enter button 13, but my loop still won't stop for some reason.

Comment: cin >> plainText reads from the input up to, but excluding, the first whitespace character. Maybe std::getline(cin, plainText) could work.

Comment: `std::ios::skipws` has no effect on `std::istream::get`.  Only formatted input ('>>') skips white space.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
int fabcd[25],number_of_items = 0;
cout << "The read in loop lasts while you don't hit space:\n";
char a;
while((a=cin.get()) != ' ')
{

        fabcd[number_of_items]=a;
        number_of_items++;      
}   
return 0;
```

Comment: This is incorrect, and will go into an endless loop on end of file.  `std::cin::get()` returns an `int` for a reason, and it is _always_ incorrect to assign it to a `char` before having tested for end of file.

Comment: @JamesKanze, yes it's int, but it can be assigned to a char

Comment: With loss of important information.  In correct code, you cannot assign it t6o a `char` _before_ having ensured that it isn't `EOF` (typically -1, but guaranteed to be negative).

Comment: @JamesKanze, how can you expect any `EOF` here? well but you are right that you do need to check `EOF` before convert it to `char` if needed.

Comment: The same way you get end of file anywhere.  How can you be sure that there will be no end of file?

Comment: The key point, of course, is that on an 8 bit machine, `std::istream::get` may return 257 different values.  That's _why_ it returns `int`, and not `char`.  (You could use `while ( std::cin.get( a ) && a != ' ' )`, however.)  Checking for success is important, because any time there is failure on input, the stream will continue to return failure (`EOF` from `std::istream::get()`) until the error has been cleared.  An endless loop in your example.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h >
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int fabcd[25],number_of_items = 0;
    cout << "The read in loop lasts while you don't hit space:\n";
    while( _kbhit() != 32  )
    {
            char ch =getche();
            if (ch != 32 )
            {
           cin >> fabcd[number_of_items];
            number_of_items++;
            }
            else
                break;

    }   
    cout << "\nnumber of items:"<<number_of_items;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what language?  That's not C++, and on the few platforms which support `<conio.h>`, it's deprecated.  It's a holdover from MS-DOS (where it was a holdover from CP/M), and you should never use `<conio.h>` in new code.